# 100% div's outer and inner

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div that will be 100% of the window (for that I use in the css fixed top 0 bottom 0 height 100%)

Inside that div I have more 2 div - one for title and one for content

The title div is 65px height, and I want the content div to be 100% of the left window (100% - 65px) - when I just give 100% it make it 100% but it goes "out" of window, because the 65px title div

How can I make the content div 100% - 65px ?

How can I get that to be 100% consider the title div...?

Comment: Use the [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). `height: calc(100% - 65px);`

Comment: Hey Jacob, I need it to be cross browser supported...

Comment: `calc()` has pretty good support, IE 9+

Comment: Since the title has a set height, why not just position the content absolutely, 65px from the top of the page?

Comment: Nice - don't think about it, but want to know if it has some other solution - not with positions...

Comment: I agree with Jacob, the only other thing I can think of that should work in all other browsers is to make the content div 100% height and width and put the header inside of the content div, position absolute. Then give the content a padding top of 65px.

Comment: If you don't want to use positions, calc, or JS, then I don't think you are going to find a solution.

Comment: position absolute - not get the solution... the height 100% still get it a overflow...

Comment: don't set the height to 100%, set `top:65px` and `bottom:0;`

Comment: like this http://codepen.io/matthsiung/pen/XKVApL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing your problem in the comments, the best way to solve this *in your case* is to absolutely position the content element `65px` from the top, like:

```
.content{
  position:absolute;
  top: 65px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/37my78e0/)

However, if you don't have to support older browsers(IE 8), you could also use CSS's [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
.content{
  height: calc(100% - 65px);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vc9x1wx3/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JQuery solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ev4b2c0/

```
var windowSize = $(window).height();
windowSize -= 65;
$("#second").css("height", windowSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using negative margin.

`margin-top: -65px`

Comment: It's go over my title div...

Comment: My bad, I meant positive margin. `margin-top: 65px`

Comment: the problem is that the content div goes more 65px down the window... it's start in good position - margin-top: 65px will make it 130px down the window...

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what your issue is, then. From my understanding, the title div is somehow pushing the content div down. Am I not understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: I have 2 div - title and content - And a div that wrap them. the title div have 65px height, the content div supposed to be 100% height of window include the 65px of the title div - BUT - it don't calculate it and make it 100% - what happens is that the content div is overflow the window and I have in the end of it border 5px - I want it to be shown...